# Bluecove & JavaFX -> application threads are not killed/stopped

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, bluetooth, bluecove

I use Bluevoce last version (2.1.1 Snapshot).

I have a `JavaFX` application that runs a **Bluetooth Server** on Windows (for the moment).

So far I can manage :

1. Waiting for a client to connect with `StreamConnectionNotifier.acceptAndOpen()` ;
2. Connexion is successfully made with an Android application I made ;
3. Messages can be sent both ways without a problem ;

For a responsive design and enhanced performance, my JavaFX uses asynchronism pattern for all **Bluetooth related events** (connexion, waiting for client, disconnexion, readind/writing data) so that the UI stays **as smooth as possible** (same thing goes for Android as well!) with **callbacks** to update the UI accordingly.

To handle threads in the cleanest and easiest way, I created a very simple class called `AsyncUtils`. This class internally manages a **threadpool** to perform operations in background and exposes one public method: `executeAsync()`. This is the complete code :

```
/**
 * Class helper offering solution to execute any give operations in an asynchronous way thanks
 * to the usage of threads and threadpools. C# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() equivalent
 */
public final class AsyncUtils {
    private final static ExecutorService executor = 
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

    /**
     * Execute the given runnable in a threadpool internally managed by a <code>ExecutorService</code>
     * @param runAsync  the runnable to run in an asynchronous operation
     * @throws  IllegalArgumentException in case the runnable is null
     * @see ExecutorService
     * @see Executors
     */
    public static void executeAsync(final Runnable runAsync) {
        if (runAsync == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("runAsync MUST NOT be NULL");
        executor.execute(runAsync);
    }
}
```

So each time I need to process an operation **outside the main UI Thread**, I delegate it to `AsyncUtils.executeAsync()`.

I have been using this pattern in many other applications (Android as well) without any problem (or at least anyproblem I might be aware of...).

However with **Bluecove**, I don't understand because when **I close the window of my JavaFX application**, my IDE (**NetBeans**) shows that the application is **still running** preventing me from restarting it.

Even worse, in the case I asynchronously call `StreamConnectionNotifier.acceptAndOpen()` and then close the application, my phone can still connect to the server! Which clearly shows that the call is still blocking and the thread running it is still alived. But that is normal behaviour.

In the case where the end-user whishes to start the **Bluetooth Server** and then close the app, **the app should completely close and stop**. So I tried two solutions to make that happen, **in vain** :

1. I added a `shutdownNow()` method in `AsyncUtils` that directly calls `executor.shutdownNow()`. But as the documation says :

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of
>   waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting
>   execution.

It **attempts** meaning it might not work which is clearly my case.

2. In my `BluetoothManager` class (where I handle everything Bluetooth related) I created a method `stopServices()` which performs a `StreamConnectionNotifier.close()`. There does not seem to be any documentation for that method but with the debugger, I tried the following :

   - Placing a break point at the line where I wait for `StreamConnectionNotifier.acceptAndOpen()` to return (meaning either a client connects or, what I would like to happen, the process is stopped and it does not wait anymore) ;
   - Closing the application and catching that request so that I can tell the BluetoothManager to stop everything : `Stage.setOnCloseRequest() =>`StreamConnectionNotifier.close()`

What happens is that `acceptAndOpen` does return BUT my application is **still running** (and no I did not forget about releasing the debugger ^^).

Further tests where I put a `System.out.println("Thread execution completed in asyncStartBluetoothServer");` shows that the message is indeed printed meaning I reached the end of the scope of `AsyncUtils.executeAsync()`. At this point, the thread should be dead because nothing to do anymore.

I also tried not using `AsyncUtils.executeAsync()` when calling `StreamConnectionNotifier.acceptAndOpen()` but it did not help : in fact it freezes the UI (as expected) and the application is still running...

Did anyone had threading problem with Bluecove ?

Perhaps I am looking at the wrong thread. But the only other case where I use `AsyncUtils.executeAsync()` is for sending message (which I am not) and listening for incoming messages (with a blocking `InputStream.read()`) but that does not make any sense, because I only start reading after `StreamConnectionNotifier.acceptAndOpen()` and in the same thread (same scope) ! And since I asked to close the `StreamConnectionNotifier`, I should not be able to use the streams with `StreamConnectionopenDataInputStream()` because there is no connected client...

Answer (score 0):

Well, after multiple tests it would seem a combination of both `StreamConnectionNotifier.close()` and `AsyncUtils.shutdownNow()` works.

But in some case the `ExecutorService` seems not to shut down when exception are thrown inside one of its threads (because calling `StreamConnectionNotifier.close()`does raise a few exception both in my code and internally.

But I managed to make my application fully stopping.

I have other details regarding this issue I will post them here.